# UPDATE based on multiple "WHERE IN" conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table I want to update based on multiple conditions. Each of these conditions is an equal-sized array, and the only valid cases are the ones which match the same index in the arrays.

That is, if we use the following SQL clause

```
UPDATE Foo
SET bar = 1
WHERE a IN ( 1,   2,   3,   4,   5)
  AND b IN ( 6,   7,   8,   9,   0)
  AND c IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

`bar` will be set to 1 for any row which has, for example, `a = 1, b = 8, c = 'e'`.

That ***is not*** what I want.

I need a clause where only `a = 1, b = 6, c = 'a'` or `a = 2, b = 7, c = 'b'` (etc.) works.

Obviously I could rewrite the clause as

```
UPDATE Foo
SET bar = 1
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 6 AND c = 'a')
   OR (a = 2 AND b = 7 AND c = 'b')
   OR ...
```

This would work, but it's hardly extensible. Given the values of the conditions are variable and obtained programmatically, it'd be far better if I could set each array in one place instead of having to build a string-building loop to get that WHERE call right.

So, is there a better, more elegant way to have the same behavior as this last block?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?   The obvious way to do it would be to have a lookup table

Comment: @JasonGoemaat This clause is run within a R script. The script collects data from table `Foo`, performs operations on it and identifies rows which need to have the flag `bar` modified. These rows are uniquely described by their columns `a, b, c`. If I could just use the simple `WHERE IN` clause at the top of this post, I'd just bind the lists to the query and be done with it. Unfortunately that would incorrectly update some rows.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with R's database access, do they have a method to pass table-valued parameters?  Creating a user-defined-table-type with the three columns and passing the values to a stored procedure to do the update would probably perform best.  How many combinations of values are you thinking?  Dos the library to access SQL server take parameterized values (i.e. `update Foo set bar = @bar` and pass a value as @bar`)?  If creating just a string to pass to sql server, I think @Gordon's answer is probably best, though you're limited to 1000 rows I think.  Don't forget to sanitize the inputs.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat table-valued parameters aren't implemented in R (afaik), but parameterized values are. I just can't figure out how to write such a parameterized call for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `values()` and `join`:

```
UPDATE f
    SET bar = 1
    FROM Foo f JOIN
         (VALUES (1, 6, 'a'),
                 (2, 7, 'b'),
                 . . .
         ) v(a, b, c)
         ON f.a = v.a AND f.b = v.b AND f.c = v.c;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Table Values Constructor :

```
UPDATE f 
SET bar = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,6,'a'),(2,7,'b'),(3,8,'c')) AS Trios(a,b,c)
   WHERE Trios.a = f.a AND Trios.b = f.b AND Trios.c = f.c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might work

```
DECLARE @Temp AS Table ( a int, b int, c varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Temp(a,b,c)
VALUES(1, 6, 'a'),
(2, 7, 'b'),
(3, 8, 'c'),
(4, 9, 'd'),
(5, 0, 'e')


UPDATE F
SET bar = 1
FROM FOO F INNER JOIN @Temp T 
ON F.a = T.a AND  F.b = T.b AND  F.c = T.c
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the data don't save it as separated values but as a single string and then use the following:

```
update foo
set bar = 1
where concat(a,b,c) in ('16a','27b','38c','49d','50e')
```

it may not be the most elegant way but it is very practical and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I could be entirely off the mark here--I'm not sure if you're passing in a set of values or what-have-you--but my first thought is using a series of CTEs.

I'm making considerable assumptions about your data, but here's an example you can run in SSMS based on my thoughts of your question.

```
-- Create @Data and insert some, er... data ---
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( id INT IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY, a VARCHAR(1), b VARCHAR(1), c VARCHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO @Data ( a ) VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5');
INSERT INTO @Data ( b ) VALUES ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'), ('0');
INSERT INTO @Data ( c ) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e');
```

So let's assume this is your data. I've kept it simple to make it easier to understand.

```
+-----+---+---+---+
| id  | a | b | c |
+-----+---+---+---+
| 100 | 1 |   |   |
| 101 | 2 |   |   |
| 102 | 3 |   |   |
| 103 | 4 |   |   |
| 104 | 5 |   |   |
| 105 |   | 6 |   |
| 106 |   | 7 |   |
| 107 |   | 8 |   |
| 108 |   | 9 |   |
| 109 |   | 0 |   |
| 110 |   |   | a |
| 111 |   |   | b |
| 112 |   |   | c |
| 113 |   |   | d |
| 114 |   |   | e |
+-----+---+---+---+
```

Query the data with aligned "array" indexes:

```
;WITH CTE_A AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS a_row_id,
        a
    FROM @Data WHERE a IS NOT NULL
)
, CTE_B AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS b_row_id,
        b
    FROM @Data WHERE b IS NOT NULL
)
, CTE_C AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS c_row_id,
        c
    FROM @Data WHERE c IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
    CTE_A.id, CTE_A.a_row_id, CTE_A.a
    , CTE_B.id, CTE_B.b_row_id, CTE_B.b
    , CTE_C.id, CTE_C.c_row_id, CTE_C.c
FROM CTE_A
JOIN CTE_B ON CTE_A.a_row_id = CTE_B.b_row_id
JOIN CTE_C ON CTE_A.a_row_id = CTE_C.c_row_id;
```

Which returns:

```
+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+
| id  | a_row_id | a | id  | b_row_id | b | id  | c_row_id | c |
+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+
| 100 |        1 | 1 | 105 |        1 | 6 | 110 |        1 | a |
| 101 |        2 | 2 | 106 |        2 | 7 | 111 |        2 | b |
| 102 |        3 | 3 | 107 |        3 | 8 | 112 |        3 | c |
| 103 |        4 | 4 | 108 |        4 | 9 | 113 |        4 | d |
| 104 |        5 | 5 | 109 |        5 | 0 | 114 |        5 | e |
+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+-----+----------+---+
```

Again, assumptions made on your data (in particular an id exists that can be sorted), but this basically pivots it by linking the a, b and c values on their relative "index" (ROW_NUMBER). By using ROW_NUMBER in this way, we can create a makeshift array index value ( a_row_id, b_row_id, c_row_id ) that can be used to join the resulting values.

This example can easily be changed to an UPDATE statement.

Does this address your question?